# for loop to iterate through some file nth position

Tags: shell, for

How do I iterate for nth file in a for loop in unix?
below some code I have tried but not succeeded

```
#!/bin/bash
#
n=2
array=( "CTL_MLPOSDTLP1_1.ctl" "CTL_MLPOSDTLP1_2.ctl" "CTL_MLPOSDTLP1_3.ctl" )
for x in "${array[@]}"
for ((x=${array[@]}; x<=n; x++));
do
echo "array[x]"
done
```

Comment: What do you mean by "some file nth position"?   What is the expected/desired output?

Comment: @roaima: I respect John1024, and I believe that he has written many answers much better than this one.   It is an adequate answer to the questions “How do I iterate through the elements of an array?” and “How do I access elements of an array by their index numbers?” — questions that have probably been asked at least a handful of times, and have probably received answers that are clearer and more coherent, elsewhere.   … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  I’m concerned that (1) anybody who wants to know how to iterate through the elements of an array won’t find this question, or ***won’t recognize it** as being equivalent to their question,* because of how poorly this one is worded, and (2) anybody who wants to know what this question *appears* to be asking (how do I look at every other (i.e., every 2nd) element of an array?) won’t be satisfied by John’s answer.

Comment: @roaima: But my point is that it’s a duplicate answer.  If the question is incomprehensible, how are we to choose one that means the same thing?

Comment: @G-Man I've no strong feelings either way. I'll pull out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways to loop over an array:

```
#!/bin/bash
array=( "CTL_MLPOSDTLP1_1.ctl" "CTL_MLPOSDTLP1_2.ctl" "CTL_MLPOSDTLP1_3.ctl" )

echo Loop 1
for x in "${array[@]}"
do
    echo "$x"
done

echo Loop 2
for ((x=0; x<${#array[@]}; x++));
do
    echo "${array[x]}"
done
```

#### Looping over selected items

This scripts allows you to specify on the command line which elements from the array ate to be processed:

```
#!/bin/bash
array=( "CTL_MLPOSDTLP1_1.ctl" "CTL_MLPOSDTLP1_2.ctl" "CTL_MLPOSDTLP1_3.ctl" )

for x in "$@"
do
    echo "${array[x]}"
done
```

Suppose we want to loop over the first two and skip the third.  (Since `bash` uses zero-based indexing, the first two are number 0 and number 1.)  Use:

```
$ bash script.sh 0 1
CTL_MLPOSDTLP1_1.ctl
CTL_MLPOSDTLP1_2.ctl
```

To run just the third:

```
$ bash s.sh 2
CTL_MLPOSDTLP1_3.ctl
```

#### To iterate from `0` to `n-1`

```
for ((x=0; x<n; x++));
do
    echo "${array[x]}"
done
```

Comment: but how abt if i want to iterate only 2 time ? means only for 2 files from the array i want to do some operation and skip the 3rd file as i dont want it for this time .. may next time i want to iterate all files in the array list?

Comment: @sabyasachikar OK. I added a script which lets you select from the command line which array elements to process.  See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks @John, nice information on zero based indexing :) ... but i want it inside the shell,not from the command line as i need to take the nth value from a config file. Regards sabya

Comment: What is your config file format?  Is there any other information that I need that you haven't told me yet?

Comment: if u look in my code i hv declared n=2 (for testing) , only that value i am taking from the config file which is generally change time to time , nothing apart from that ..

Comment: OK.  I added code for iterating from 0 to n.

Comment: that code iterate from numeric value 0 to nth , not file .

Comment: Yes and the corresponding file name is `${array[x]}`.

Comment: Thank you , i hv tried with it but its not restrict the loop in 2nd file.. it showing all file as output

Comment: OK.  I adjusted the loop to go from 0 to `n-1`.  With n=2, that would mean that you get elements 0 and 1. but not 2.

Comment: +1. Good answers in this time window do not get enough love

Answer (score 0):

```
#!bin/bash
n=2
array=( "CTL_MLPOSDTLP1_1.ctl" "CTL_MLPOSDTLP1_2.ctl" "CTL_MLPOSDTLP1_3.ctl" )
for ((x=0; x<=n-1; x++));
do
    echo "${array[x]}"
done
```

Thanks @john for the help as I edited and got the correct output; it's working now :)